# PHP CSV export saves as unicode text instead of CSV

Tags: php, csv, unicode, export-to-csv

I have a problem with exporting to csv from php. When I export to csv it works fine. I can open it and edit it. But when I want 'to save as' the edited file it says *save as Unicode Text (.txt)*

I would like to Save directly as CSV. The exported file name has a CSV extension. This is my code:

```
    $filename = "export-".date("d-m-Y").".csv";
    ob_end_clean();
    $filePath = 'php://output';
    header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
    header('Content-Type: application/csv; charset=UTF-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="'.$filename.'";');
    $f = fopen($filePath, 'w');
    echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF"; // UTF-8 BOM

    $header = array();
    // GET CURRENT HEADERS
    foreach ($data[0] as $key => $value) {
        array_push($header,$key);
    }
    fputcsv($f, $header, $delimiter);
    //unset($data['headers']);
    foreach ($data as $line) {
        fputcsv($f, $line, $delimiter);
    }
    fclose($f);
```

I tried several different headers, but none worked. I Googled and searched Stackoverflow but I seem to be the only one having this problem. Is someone familiar with this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the UTF-8 BOM.

Had a similar issue, removing the BOM prevented this behaviour, but need to confirm that UTF-8 characters are still displayed correctly etc. Not fully tested yet.